# python for loop iterators and int( , 16)

Tags: python, for-loop, int

My query is for the following example :

```
c0b0="FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 7F"
print c0b0
for ch in c0b0:
    a=str(ch)
    print "{0}  {1}".format(ch,type(ch))
    print hex(int(ch,16))
```

If you see the output :

```
sh-4.3$ python main.py                                                                                                                                               
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 7F                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
F  <type 'str'>                                                                                                                                                      
0xf                                                                                                                                                                  
F  <type 'str'>                                                                                                                                                      
0xf                                                                                                                                                                  
   <type 'str'>                                                                                                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                   
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>                                                                                                                                
    print hex(int(ch,16))                                                                                                                                            
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''
```

Seeing this we can certainly say ch is not tuple but string. But still int(ch, 16) consider ch invalid literals.

Can someone point out where I'm missing and how it will work with int( ,16)?

Comment: Youre trying to convert a space to an int, a space is invalid hex

Comment: int() is failing when you try to interpret a space as a base 16 number. You can checking that the character you are about to parse is between 0 and F before trying to parse it.

Comment: The error message tells you *exactly* what is wrong: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''` i.e., you are passing whitespace to `int`, because you are iterating over each of the characters. It looks like you meant to `.split` your input first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `for ch in c0b0`, you're iterating over the individual characters of your initial string, not over the space-separated pairs of hex digits. Your code fails on the first space.

I think you want `for ch in c0b0.split()`, which  first divides up the original string into a list of strings (splitting on whitespace), before iterating over the list.

Comment: With "for ch in c0b0.split()" , space check can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You should skip `space`. For this `space`, you are getting this error .

```
c0b0="FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 7F"
print c0b0
for ch in c0b0.split(" "):
    a=str(ch)
    print "{0}  {1}".format(ch,type(ch))
    print hex(int(ch,16))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for pointing out the space to me, yes it worked with following code:

```
c0b0="FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 7F" 
print c0b0 
for ch in c0b0:
        if(ch == " "):
            continue
        a=str(ch)
        print "{0}  {1}".format(ch,type(ch))
        print hex(int(ch,16))
```